# Why is Wordpress $wpdb->query() response 1 when the rows returned is 0

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm doing the following in a custom function:

```
    $exists = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare('
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM wp_%d_gdsr_data_article
    WHERE post_id = %d

', $blog_id, $post_id));
```

$exists evaluates to 1 even if no rows are returned by the query. Also, var_dump($wpdb->queries) yields a NULL. Anyone know what is going on here?

thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class):

> The function returns an integer
>   corresponding to the number of rows
>   affected/selected. If there is a MySQL
>   error, the function will return FALSE.
>   (Note: since both 0 and FALSE can be
>   returned, make sure you use the
>   correct comparison operator: equality
>   == vs. identicality ===).

The query returns 1 row so the `query()` function returns `1` - and will always return `1` for the query that you post in your question, even if the number of rows selected by the `COUNT` is 0.  Use `get_var`, `get_row`, or `get_results` as suggested by TheDeadMedic to get the actual result of the query, which might be `0`, `1`, `2`, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Use `$wpdb->get_var($query)` instead.

Accordingly, use `$wpdb->get_row()` to retrieve a single row as a single object (or array), and `$wpdb->get_results()` to get a result set.

Comment: Thanks but why would it return 1 when it is supposed to return a row count? Also any idea why $wpdb->queries is empty?

Comment: `$wpdb->query()` should only be used for executable queries, as it only returns the number of rows or false if no rows. `$wpdb->queries` is only utilised if you define `SAVEQUERIES` as true.